# error when installing xna 4 for visual studio 2013 - VSIX

Tags: visual-studio, xna, installation

I tried for about 2 hours to install xna on my visual studio 2013 but I didn't succeed.

I downloaded this xna version: https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230  .
the error occurs when I run the XNA Game Studio 4.0 VSIX file.

error log:

```
07/08/2014 18:44:58 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
07/08/2014 18:44:58 - -------------------------------------------
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - Initializing Install...
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - Extension Details...
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   Identifier      : bcc70cc4-703d-4f8b-98f5-d96bfc71335b
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   Name            : XNA Game Studio 4.0
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   Author          : Microsoft
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   Version         : 1.4.12
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   Description     : XNA Game Studio Package provides game development experiences for Xbox 360, Windows, and Windows Phone.
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   Locale          : en-US
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   MoreInfoURL     : 
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   InstalledByMSI  : False
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - 
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   Supported Products : 
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinDesktopExpress
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - 
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -   References      : 
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       -------------------------------------------------------
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.12.0
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       Name         : Visual Studio MPF 12.0
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       Version      : [12.0]
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       MoreInfoURL  : 
07/08/2014 18:44:59 -       Nested       : No
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - 
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - 
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - Searching for applicable products...
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - Found installed product - Global Location
07/08/2014 18:44:59 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I remeber from school this year, they said that Visual Studio 2012 or higher didn't work well with XNA. What I can recommand you that may solve the problem until you find a clear answer for it is to get back to Visual Studio 2010. I used it all the time this year and XNA worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the output states:

Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows

Which has the following description on Microsoft's site:

You can use the tools in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows to create innovative and compelling **Windows Phone and Windows Store apps** on Windows 8.1.

XNA doesn't run on either, so you want **Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop**.